# JS: Display image from numpy array

Tags: javascript, image, binary

I have a binary file that I read using python numpy, and for the moment I display this file as an image using matplotlib:

[image]

I need to display this image in my App (Electron JS App), but not as a .jpg, as a dynamic image (so I can use the mouse to see the data).
I know there are some python libraries for this (like plotly), but couldnt find something similar for js.

My main idea is to do all the process using javascript not python:
so I will need to read the binary files, reshape the array, and display it...

Any ideas are welcome.